# AWS ruby sdk: how to create a security group with relaxed (permit all) permissions

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-security-group

I have installed the AWS ruby sdk.

`gem install aws-sdk`

Within irb:

`require aws-sdk`

Now I want to create a security group with all packets permitted both incoming and outgoing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/SecurityGroup.html#authorize_ingress-instance_method), I believe you would need to make three calls to `authorize_ingress` to accomplish this:

```
security_group.authorize_ingress(:tcp, 0..65535)
security_group.authorize_ingress(:udp, 0..65535)
security_group.authorize_ingress(:icmp, 0..65535)
```